# Associate Google domain name to Python Flask website hosted at home

Tags: dns, bind

1. I have a Python Flask website which runs on my home system and
   is accessible to the Internet by home ISP IP address assigned to me and
   x port number. I have taken care of port forwarding from router, etc.
2. I bought a Google domain name.
3. I want to run Python Flask
   website from my home IP which should have a Google domain name I bought.

Any pointers on how to do this? I do not expect an answer to be full flown how-to, but a pointer in right direction would help as well.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Your question is too general and you provide too little detail.  What have you done so far and what doesn't work?  When you say "IP address assigned to me and x port number", do you mean that there is any sort of port forwarding done on another server because DNS entries do not refer to ports?  Are you sure your ISP allows and lets the connection through?

Answer (score 0):

If your home IP changes from time to time, then what you're looking for is Dynamic DNS.  Most internet routers that you would get from your ISP support DynDNS records, and even if yours doesn't setting up a script to update the Dynamic DNS record is easy.

What Dynamic DNS does is make a query to the DNS service, and update your domain (or subdomain) record to always point to your home IP.  And when your home IP changes, the script updates it.

For google domains, start here:  https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en